# Visual Studio 2017 (C++): Accessing a Variable from Project A in Project B in the same Solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I got an actually quite simple Problem to solve, but I'm not sure, how to handle with it.

So I have two different Projects. Project A and Project B.
Both are in the same Solution.

I can not put the Source Code from Project A to Project B because both of them have different Build Environments.

**Now the Problem:** I want to use a variable from Project A in Project B.

How the Hell do I get Access to this variable the easiest way?

I thought about creating a little UDP Server to send it over or writing into a text-file and reading it, but isn't there a easier, less overkill way to connect both Projects and do something like:

```
Project_A ProA;


ProB_Variable = ProA.myVariable;
```

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The question isn't how to do that, it is why would you want to do that. Global Variables are bad, trying to export them to other projects is even worse.

Comment: Projects don't exist. When your computer is running the program it doesn't know about projects. It does know about programs, or DLLs, or whatever you are creating out of those projects. Are they programs?

Comment: Project A should be designed as a library, it's build environment should be fixed (or a new build should be created) to be compatible with Project B, and it should not use global variables if at all possible.

Comment: @Eric I know. The biggest Problem is, that Project A is a Qt Project with a Qt Build Environment and lots of Properties which are needed for the Project to run. Project B is a Simulation Build Environment which as been created by it's own with it's own Properties and libs which are needed to run it.

Comment: The answer might be: No, there is not a simple way.

Comment: @Cptain_Whitebeard: The whole point of a simulation is that it is NOT the real thing. Why does your simulation depend on the real thing?! Visual Studio helps you here, by stopping muddled thinking.

Comment: I suggest that you could try to use the [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), declare the function pointer in B, and assign it a value in A, so that the function of the A item can be called by using the function pointer in the B project.**NOTE:** We need to declare the function pointer as a static global variable and then assign it in the initialization of A, otherwise it may cause a null pointer to be called in subsequent operations.